# How can I find documents in MongoDB using a variable as collection?

Tags: mongodb, variables, find, pymongo

I want to use the following commands:

```
coll = sys.argv[1]
docs = db.coll.find()
```

That does not work. If I hardcode it like this it works:

```
docs = db.collection_I_want_to_query.find()
```

I guess the find-function does not work because coll is a string. But is there a possibility to use variables for querying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#getting-a-database

```
col = sys.argv[1]
db[col].find()
```